# How to run a function in background in django python only when it is called?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-celery, background-task

I have created an email functionality which will send access token to the user for verification.
This process takes little time to execute.

So, I want to push this function in background and notify the user with the message "The access token would be mailed to your email id. Please check you email". This is to keep user updated rather than him waiting for the access token notification once the whole task is completed.

I don't want to schedule as it is not required here and Django's background_task module won't help I suppose.

What could be the way-out?

Comment: How long does the email take to send? Surprising that it would take so long to be an issue

Comment: sometimes it takes up to 30 seconds.

Comment: To send an access token in an email?? If you don't want to use some async queue then you may get away with doing this with ajax

Comment: you can use thread in this case

Comment: Before sending the access token, I'm verifying if the user is already active or if he's sending duplicate requests. Once the user's basic details are verified, we send out the access token.
This whole process takes 30 to 50 seconds.

Comment: @Ask_Ashu If it takes 30-50 seconds you should definitely use an async task. Can you add the code that performs these checks and sends the email to your question?

Comment: If it take 30s to send a mail, you should fix your mail setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [celery](https://pypi.org/project/celery/)? I think it is doing exactly what you need if I am not wrong.

Comment: I was not going for celery as this won't be an async task but I'll try to use celery to push the function in the background.

Comment: Yes, it's really useful and you can track task progress using ajax or socket according to your need.

Comment: it worked using celery and it's .delay() functionality.

Comment: Happy to know it's working. I think it's time to upvote.